How to data migrate large hdfs file (>12GB) from source to destination server without change "rpc-max-received-response-size"?
I am working on data migration on hdfs files from the old server to the new one.
I tried to use "hadoop dist" and "hdfs archive" to transfer large size of hdfs file from source to destination server. I also tried to download the file to local. Unfortunately, I failed. I always received error message "RPC response exceeds maximum data length".
The source serve is dying and does not allow to change the "rpc-max-received-response-size". How can I transfer the large hdfs files to the new server efficiently? Any further advice would be highly appreciated.
